# How to marshal two dimensional TCHAR array?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a DLL function in that converts a file to another format.
The function produces multiple files as output.
Therefore, it fills the 2nd parameter with the paths of the output files.

The C++ function is defined as the following:

```
int Convert(LPTSTR lpSource, TCHAR outputFileName[][MAX_PATH]);
```

How do I mashal the 2nd parameter so that my C# application can receive the output file paths correctly?

```
[DllImport("Convert.dll")]
private static extern int Convert(
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszSource,
  ????
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to marshal it as a 1D array and transfer it to the proper 2D one programmatically.

Comment: First of all, thank you for helping. I tried 'ref string[] lpszOutputFileName' and got an System.ExecutionException after the function returns. I also tried many different ways but none of them worked. Not sure how to do it properly, still exploring.

Comment: That C++ function is fundamentally dangerous, it has no way of knowing how large an array was passed.  This fails in very unpleasant ways when the function corrupts the GC heap, ExecutionEngineException is a common outcome.  Fix the C++ code first.

Comment: I fixed the C++ function by changing it to int Convert(LPTSTR lpSource, TCHAR outputFileName[][MAX_PATH], int numberOfOutputFiles); I still don't have any idea on how to marshal the 2nd parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
I changed my C++ function to the following:

```
int Convert(LPTSTR lpSource, LPTSTR *plpOutputFileName, int size);
```

And the C# declaration as:

```
[DllImport("Convert.dll")]
private static extern int Convert(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszSource,
    [In, Out] String[] outputFileName,
    int size
);
```

Thank you all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I would make things simpler using **C++/CLI** (which is very good at building *bridging* layers between native C/C++ code and managed code).

Basically, you could write a thin C++/CLI layer that exposes a method that calls the native function in its body, and then copies the returned native strings into a `gcnew`-ly created **`array<String^>`**, and returns it to the C# managed caller.